# Adding another state (spam, reject, approve) to wordpress comments?

Tags: custom-field, customization, comments, metabox, comment-meta

i know this might sound a bit weird, but what I'm trying to do is rather simple in mind but may be technically difficult.

I'm running small contests on my wordpress site where I ask users to leave a comment. I'm selecting a comment after a certain period of time and this is the winner.

What I'd like to do now, is mark that comment as winner.

So, I'm thinking of a solution like this: When viewing the comments in /wp-admin I can set a comment as spam, approved, rejected, etc. I'd like to have another Link/Button that says: "winner". If I click this link the comment has an additional class like `<li class="comment odd alt thread-even depth-1 winner">`

Is there a clever solution that comes to your mind? How can I do that?
Any other ideas?

Thank you in advance.
Matt

Comment: Why not use comment meta instead?

Comment: How would I do that with my goal in mind? Can you maybe be a little preciser in explaing how to use comment meta for my aim?

Comment: Once i have the time available to provide an answer with details i'll be happy to, for now maybe you can consult [`get_comment_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta) and [`add_comment_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta) docs for examples of getting and setting comment meta.

Comment: Managed to find some spare time, so i've thrown together an answer for you, i hope it's helpful.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you'd like the facility to update this data from the quickedit box whilst viewing the list of comments, you'll need a series of actions and filters. I've tried to make appropriate comments in the necessary places for you, though bear in mind i threw this all together for you with a small amount of testing(it does work though).

This should get give you a good starting point...

```
// Add new heading to comments tables
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', 'winner_comment_column' );
function winner_comment_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['winning_comment'] = __( 'Winning Comment' );
    return $columns;
}

// Print comment meta for new meta column
add_action( 'manage_comments_custom_column', 'myplugin_comment_column', 10, 2 );
function myplugin_comment_column( $column, $comment_ID ) {
    if ( 'winning_comment' != $column )
        return;
    echo esc_attr( get_comment_meta( $comment_ID, 'win_comment', true ) );
}

// Replace the quickedit action to call an additional expandedOpen function
add_filter( 'comment_row_actions', 'my_quick_edit_action', 10, 2 );
function my_quick_edit_action( $actions, $comment ) {
    global $post;
    $actions['quickedit'] = '<a onclick="commentReply.close();if( typeof(expandedOpen) == \'function\' ) expandedOpen('.$comment->comment_ID.');commentReply.open( \''.$comment->comment_ID.'\',\''.$post->ID.'\',\'edit\' );return false;" class="vim-q" title="'.esc_attr__( 'Quick Edit' ).'" href="#">' . __( 'Quick Edit' ) . '</a>';
    return $actions;
}

// Add some javscript into the footer for the edit comments page
add_action('admin_footer-edit-comments.php', 'my_quick_edit_javascript');
function my_quick_edit_javascript() {

    // Create nonce
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'my_cmeta' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function expandedOpen(id) {
        // Pull the data from the new column and pass that along to our new input
        var mv = jQuery('tr#comment-'+id+' .column-winning_comment').text() || '';
        jQuery('#comment-meta-mycustommeta').val(mv);
    }
    function saveCommentMeta() {
        // Build the data object for the ajax action setup to update comment meta
        var cid = jQuery('#comment_ID').val() || 0;
        var mv  = jQuery('#comment-meta-mycustommeta').val() || '';
        var data = {
            action: "update_winning_comment",
            _ajax_nonce: "<?php echo $nonce; ?>",
            comment_ID: cid,
            comment_metaKey: 'win_comment',
            comment_metaValue: mv
        };
        // Post data to ajax
        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if( 'success' != response )
                return;
            // Valid response, update the new table column(so you don't need to refresh)
            jQuery('tr#comment-'+cid+' .column-winning_comment').text(mv);
            // Close the quickedit
            commentReply.close();
        });
    };
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Setup ajax callback for the new action
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_winning_comment', 'update_winning_comment_ajax' );
function update_winning_comment_ajax() {

    // Check nonce
    check_ajax_referer( 'my_cmeta' );
    // Check expected fields are there
    foreach( array( 'comment_ID', 'comment_metaKey', 'comment_metaValue' ) as $field )
        if( !isset( $_POST[$field] ) )
            die;

    // Validate ID
    $commentID  = absint( $_POST['comment_ID'] );
    if( !$commentID )
        die;

    // Validate meta key
    $commentKey = sanitize_title( $_POST['comment_metaKey'] );
    if( empty( $commentKey ) )
        die;

    // Validate meta value(or empty)
    $commentVal = sanitize_title( $_POST['comment_metaValue'] );

    // Update meta 
    update_comment_meta( $commentID, $commentKey, $commentVal );

    // Success response
    echo 'success';// Echoed value is received as the response
    // And die, expected behaviour for ajax actions
    die;
}

// Run filter on the comment reply box(necessary to add new fields into the quickedit box)
add_filter( 'wp_comment_reply', 'my_quick_edit_menu', 10, 2 );
function my_quick_edit_menu($str, $input) {

    extract( $input );
    $table_row = true;

    if( $mode == 'single' )
        $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Post_Comments_List_Table');
    else 
        $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Comments_List_Table');

    // Get editor string
    ob_start();
        $quicktags_settings = array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' );
    wp_editor( '', 'replycontent', array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => false, 'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings, 'tabindex' => 104 ) );
    $editorStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();


    // Get nonce string
    ob_start();    
    wp_nonce_field( "replyto-comment", "_ajax_nonce-replyto-comment", false );
        if ( current_user_can( "unfiltered_html" ) )
        wp_nonce_field( "unfiltered-html-comment", "_wp_unfiltered_html_comment", false );
    $nonceStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();


    $content = '<form method="get" action="">';
    if ( $table_row ) :
        $content .= '<table style="display:none;"><tbody id="com-reply"><tr id="replyrow" style="display:none;"><td colspan="'.$wp_list_table->get_column_count().'" class="colspanchange">';
    else :
        $content .= '<div id="com-reply" style="display:none;"><div id="replyrow" style="display:none;">';
    endif;

    $content .= '
            <div id="replyhead" style="display:none;"><h5>Reply to Comment</h5></div>
            <div id="addhead" style="display:none;"><h5>Add new Comment</h5></div>
            <div id="edithead" style="display:none;">';

    $content .= '  
                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="author">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="newcomment_author" size="50" value="" tabindex="101" id="author" />
                </div>

                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="author-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="newcomment_author_email" size="50" value="" tabindex="102" id="author-email" />
                </div>

                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="author-url">URL</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author-url" name="newcomment_author_url" size="103" value="" tabindex="103" />
                </div>';

    // Add new quick edit fields       
    $content .= '
                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="comment-meta-mycustommeta">Winner</label>
                    <input type="text" id="comment-meta-mycustommeta" name="comment-meta-mycustommeta" size="50" value="" tabindex="104" />
                    <a onclick="saveCommentMeta();" class="button-secondary save-mycustommeta" href="#">'.__( 'Save' ).'</a>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            </div>';

    // Add editor
    $content .= "<div id='replycontainer'>\n";   
    $content .= $editorStr;
    $content .= "</div>\n";  

    $content .= '          
            <p id="replysubmit" class="submit">
            <a href="#comments-form" class="cancel button-secondary alignleft" tabindex="107">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#comments-form" class="save button-primary alignright" tabindex="106">
            <span id="addbtn" style="display:none;">Add Comment</span>
            <span id="savebtn" style="display:none;">Update Comment</span>
            <span id="replybtn" style="display:none;">Submit Reply</span></a>
            <img class="waiting" style="display:none;" src="'.esc_url( admin_url( "images/wpspin_light.gif" ) ).'" alt="" />
            <span class="error" style="display:none;"></span>
            <br class="clear" />
            </p>';

        $content .= '
            <input type="hidden" name="user_ID" id="user_ID" value="'.get_current_user_id().'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_ID" id="comment_ID" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" id="comment_post_ID" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" value="'.$position.'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="';

    if ($checkbox) $content .= '1'; else $content .=  '0';
    $content .= "\" />\n";
        $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" id="mode" value="'.esc_attr( $mode ).'" />';

    $content .= $nonceStr;
    $content .="\n";

    if ( $table_row ) :
        $content .= '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    else :
        $content .= '</div></div>';
    endif;
    $content .= "\n</form>\n";
    return $content;
}
```

And should produce, something like this..

[Comment Meta - Quickedit http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/1337/commentmetaexample.jpg](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/1337/commentmetaexample.jpg)

First time i've written code for the quick edit box on the comments page, so excuse any areas that could use improvement(there's always room for it), i don't have alot of time to spend going over the code and making refinements at the moment.

Good luck, and i hope that's been helpful.

Oh, and quick mention for Shibashake's guide to messing with the Quick Edit, i used *some* of his code to put this together, so definitely deserving of some link juice.

[Shibashake - Expand the WordPress Comments Quick Edit Menu](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/expand-the-wordpress-comments-quick-edit-menu)